# Distribution function for sum of two random variables with geometric distribution

Tags: probability-theory

What would be a distribution function of a random variable $\zeta$, which is the sum of two independent random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$, which have following distribution: $P(\xi=k) = p_1 q_1^k$, $P(\eta=k) = p_2 q_2^k$? It's not exactly geometrical distribution, we're counting losses until the first win, but it's similar. We know distribution function for both of them, but what would one for their sum look like?

Comment: Just FYI, but both the "losses until first win" and "first win occurs at time $n$" variables are called "geometric".  These are just different conventions.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $$\Pr[\xi + \eta = k] = \sum_{j=0}^k \Pr[\xi = j] \Pr[\eta = k-j] = \sum_{j=0}^k p_1 q_1^j p_2 q_2^{k-j} $$ and I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Well, I kind of need the rest. I can't figure out what to do with the double sum, which we get from your expression.

Comment: It isn't a double sum.  There's only one summation symbol.  First take out terms that are independent of $j$, then figure out how to write the rest as a finite geometric series.

Comment: What you wrote is a probability of event $\xi + \eta = k$. What i need is distribution function, which is the sum of those probabilities.

Comment: That necessarily requires computing the probability mass function first.  Then deal with computing the cumulative distribution function.  It does have a closed form, but you need to compute it yourself.

Comment: What @heropup said. Plus, the distribution function is **not** "the sum of those probabilities". The sum of those probabilities is 1.